# If else condition with or, return variable that evaluates to FALSE

Tags: python

I was wondering about the most pythonic (and shortest) way to return the variable in an `if else` that evaluates to `FALSE` (or `TRUE`).

```
def foo(a,b)
    if a == 0 or b == 0:
        # return b
    else:
        pass;

a = 0 
b = 1

print(foo(a,b))
> 1
```

Comment: `else: pass` is redundant. You don't *have* to include an `else`.

Comment: And what should happen if both `a` and `b` are `0`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters doesnt really matter since I am not interested in the value then. I was just wondering if there is a way to get one of the values, if one evalutes to `FALSE`. Of course I could simply write a longer `if else` but I thought there might be shorter way :)

Comment: Next, did you mean for `a` and `b` to be treated as booleans? Then use `False` instead of `0`, `True` instead of `1`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Nope, as numbers :) But I see your confusion

Comment: There's no need to use `int()` on integer literals. It is your use of `FALSE` and `TRUE` in your question body that led me to suspect you wanted actual booleans.

Comment: @MartijnPieters a sorry. I though you got confused by the use of `1` and `0`.

Comment: What is this function actually intended to do?

Comment: @khelwood pass me the variable that evaluates to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of the `or` operator short-circuiting:

```
def foo(a, b):
    if a == 0 or b == 0:
       return a or b
```

This returns `b` if `a` is `0`. Note that if `a` and `b` are both `0`, then `0` is returned.

If you really meant for these values to be *booleans*, then use the Python `bool` type values, `False` and `True`:

```
def foo(a, b):
    if not (a and b):  # equivalent of "not a or not b"
        return a or b

foo(False, True)  # produces True
foo(True, True)  # produces None
```

Comment: I was looking for that! Thanks!

Comment: How would inverse it? Get the variable that evaluates to `TRUE`? So `0`?

Comment: @Chrissl: `a and b` returns `a` if it is false (set to `0`), `b` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but isn't it the attempt to do this:

```
a = None
b = 123

c = a or b
print(c)
> 123
```

It is a pattern for initializing parameters for the functions with defaults if non-mandatory parameter was not set:

```
def func(a, b=None):
    b = b or 'default_value'
    print(a, b)

func('abc', 'b defined')
func('cde')
```